# how to change the FloatLabeledEditText hint color dynamically from activity/fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to change the `FloatLabeledEditText` hint color dynamically using JAVA code..

below is the XML code to generate `FloatLabeledEditText` with default color

```
        <com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
        android:id="@+id/float_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
        float:fletTextAppearance="@style/floatlabelededittext">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            style="@style/EditTextWithBlackMediumSizeWithoutLeftAndTopPadding10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>
```

sample image is attached
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp18A.jpg)

Comment: use this while you validating user field, emailField.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.the_color));

Comment: I tried above code but not working for FloatLabeledEditText.In layout i added color with style using tag float:fletTextAppearance="@style/floatlabelededittext".
but not sure how to add this style dynamically using java code or atleast i need to change the text hint color.

if you see the image once. you can see the how the color is changing default to another

Comment: u are using a custom contorl, i gave you a code for default floating control, u have to read more from your custom control

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using this [github project](https://github.com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext/blob/master/library/src/com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext/FloatLabeledEditText.java).  After looking through the source code, it is possible, but only in a roundabout way.

`ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.float_email);
TextView textView = vg.getChildAt(0);`

That should return the textview that is used as a hint.  If you look at the source code, you'll see that the hint textview is set during setAttributes call.

Comment: Thanks... Its working but it is returning textview not edittext.


 ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.float_email);
   TextView     float_email = (TextView) vg.getChildAt(0);

float_email.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.tab_selected_text_color));

Comment: Thanks for helping on this.

Comment: Yeah, by bad on that.  I'll edit the answer.  Glad its working now.  I'd appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Give the guy his accepted answer, works well